# CollapsingToolbarLayout elevation not working and anchored FloatingActionButton not returning

Tags: java, android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've been trying to implement a layout [similar to this](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsRTM1M1lCWWZiN2c/patterns-scrolling-techniques-flexible_space_xhdpi_003.webm) from the material design guidelines, using the new [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). The `CollapsingToolbarLayout` seems to be the way to go, but it ignores any attempt to add elevation. Furthermore, if I set the height of the `AppBarLayout` to anything under about 144dp, the `FloatingActionButton` will pop out, but not return. Here's my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="72dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingLeft="72dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_person_add_white_24dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|start"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After diving into the source code, I discovered the `FloatingActionButton`, when attached to the `AppBarLayout`, is set to appear only when the space available is `<=appBarLayout.getMinimumHeightForVisibleOverlappingContent()`, which is 2*minimum height(the `Toolbar`, in this case), plus the status bar. So in portrait on a phone, 56*2+26 = 138dp. I confirmed this by setting mine to 138dp, which works, and 137dp does not. If you want to get around this, you can either override `getMinimumHeightForVisibleOverlappingContent()` in `AppBarLayout`, or the following method in `FloatingActionButton`:

```
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
        if(dependency instanceof SnackbarLayout) {
            this.updateFabTranslationForSnackbar(parent, child, dependency);
        } else if(dependency instanceof AppBarLayout) {
            AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout)dependency;
            if(this.mTmpRect == null) {
                this.mTmpRect = new Rect();
            }

            Rect rect = this.mTmpRect;
            ViewGroupUtils.getDescendantRect(parent, dependency, rect);
            if(rect.bottom <= appBarLayout.getMinimumHeightForVisibleOverlappingContent()) {
                if(!this.mIsAnimatingOut && child.getVisibility() == 0) {
                    this.animateOut(child);
                }
            } else if(child.getVisibility() != 0) {
                this.animateIn(child);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

As for the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` elevation, I haven't found a workaround yet.

Answer (score 2):

For `CollapsingToolbarLayout` elevation you can search in subclass `CollapsingToolbarLayout.OffsetUpdateListener` which has method `onOffsetChanged` doing the job

```
 if(Math.abs(verticalOffset) == scrollRange) {
     ViewCompat.setElevation(layout, layout.getTargetElevation());
 } else {
     ViewCompat.setElevation(layout, 0.0F);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the elevation, the collapsing toolbar layout explicitly removes the elevation when not collapsed*. It has been filed as a bug it seems:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192553&q=elevation&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

(As @Ben is saying in his answer and reference to the source code as well)

Direct link to the code (currently, line 1062):
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.java#1062

```
if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) == scrollRange) {
    // If we have some pinned children, and we're offset to only show those views,
    // we want to be elevate
    ViewCompat.setElevation(layout, layout.getTargetElevation());
} else {
    // Otherwise, we're inline with the content
    ViewCompat.setElevation(layout, 0f);
}
```